# I cannot access element by type in tuple created with forward_as_tuple

Tags: c++, c++17, perfect-forwarding, stdtuple

I am using C++17 with Visual C++ 2017 and I am creating a `std::tuple` of references using `std::forward_as_tuple`.

Since C++14 it is possible to access an element of a tuple by using a class type instead of an index.

When I try the code below I have compilation error

```
 error C2338: duplicate type T in get<T>(tuple)
```

Do you know how to access an element in a tuple created in such way?

Below the sample code

```
struct CA { 
    int data_ = 0; 
};

struct CB { 
    int data_ = 0; 
};

int main()
{
    CA a;
    CA b;

    auto joined_objects = std::forward_as_tuple(a, b);  

    std::cout << std::get<0>(joined_objects).data_ << std::endl; // works
    std::cout << std::get<CA &>(joined_objects).data_ << std::endl; // fails
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the compiler doesn't know which element you really want.

There is ambiguity because `a` and `b` have same type. `get` helper for types cannot work if tuple contains same type twice. It's pretty understandable.

Did you perhaps mean to write `CB b`? [This works.](https://godbolt.org/z/Vr0kcY)

Comment: FWIW, godbolt and gcc were helpful, because I could copy-paste code, add headers and see `... is an ambiguous base class of 'std::tuple<CA&, CA&>'` That gave it away pretty quickly.